# Font file to print QRCode in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, qr-code

I need to generate and print QRCode in vb.net, I would like to to know any font file is available which can handle this process automatically.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [QRCode](https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder/) package to generate QRCode image

install the package: `Install-Package QRCoder`

usage:

```
Dim qrGenerator As QRCodeGenerator = New QRCodeGenerator()
Dim qrCodeData As QRCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode("The text which should be encoded.", QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q)
Dim qrCode As QRCode = New QRCode(qrCodeData)
Dim qrCodeImage As Bitmap = qrCode.GetGraphic(20)

Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream
    qrCodeImage.Save("image file location", ImageFormat.Bmp)
End Using
```